# What is the correct adjective to express that you feel sympathy for people in a movie that you burst out crying?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

You watch a film.

In the film, there is a little girl lost his parents and now she becomes an orphan.

Is it correct to say

**I was so moved/emotional/ etc that I burst out crying when watching that film**?

**What is the correct adjective to express that you feel sympathy for people in a movie that you burst out crying?**

Comment: ***moved*** and ***emotional*** are fine. Also you can rephrase slightly to use different *forms* of descriptive text: *The the movie was **so poignant / touching / emotional / emotive / moving** [that it brought tears to my eyes]*, for example.

Comment: ...such movies are called [***tearjerkers***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tearjerker) or [***weepies***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/weepie).

Comment: (It's _her_ parents, by the way.) You can also say that the film **reduced you to tears**.

Comment: You can also say the film is heart-tugging, or that it tugs at your heartstrings (which means it stirs your emotions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was moved to tears.

> I was so moved that I burst into tears.

> It was so moving that I started crying.

> It made me very emotional.